# How can I match strings like "aaaaa"bbb"ddddd" using antlr4?

Tags: html, antlr, velocity

I have HTML tags in a vm file such as:

```html
<li ><a href="$urlParamTool.join($!{cate.url}, "tracelog=sourcing_home_category")">aaa</a></li>
```

In my parser, I have defined a vm refrence that can recognize `$urlParamTool.join($!{cate.url}, "tracelog=sourcing_home_category")`. I added the grammar `'"'refrence'"'` to match the whole tag, but it always recognizes `"$urlParamTool.join($!{cate.url}, "`instead.

What causes this problem, and how should I solve it?

Comment: This is a lot trickier than it looks: you have (1) stuff outside HTML tags, (2) HTML tags, (3) inside tags there are attributes en (4) anywhere in the previous 3 modes there can be code snippets: `$...` which can contain string literals again). You could try to use lexical modes: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes but it'll still be a hassle to get it right, I'm guessing.

Comment: Can you post your grammar?  Bart’s right that getting the Lexer rules right is going to be the tricky part of this, but perhaps we can provide some pointers if we can see the approach you’ve taken.  You’ll first need to focus on just getting the proper stream of tokens you can use for your parser rules.  Key point — lexer rules are not impacted by parser rules.  (Look into using the suggested grun alias to dump your token stream.)

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. So I defined a parser rule like this: dirtyStrStart ~('"'| ':' | '+' | ';')+ (DirtyStrEnd | ((DoubleStringLiteral ~('"')+)*? dirtyStr)),so i can recognize all tags as one token